# Service variable not getting cleared in angular

Tags: angular

I have this service in angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    declare var webkitSpeechRecognition: any;
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class VoiceRecognitionService {
    
      recognition =  new webkitSpeechRecognition();
      isStoppedSpeechRecog = false;
      public text = '';
      public tempWords : any;
      public transcript_arr = [];
      public confidence_arr = [];
    
    
      constructor() { }
    
      init() {
        this.recognition.continuous = true;
        this.recognition.interimResults = false;
        this.recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
        this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    
    
        this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e:any) => {
          let last = e.results.length - 1;
          let temp_trans = e.results[last][0].transcript; 
          this.transcript_arr.push(temp_trans); 
          const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
            .map((result:any) => result[0])
            .map((result) => result.transcript)
            .join(''); 
          this.tempWords = transcript;
        });
      }
    
      start() {
        this.isStoppedSpeechRecog = false;
        this.recognition.start();
        this.recognition.addEventListener('end', (condition:any) => {
          if (this.isStoppedSpeechRecog) {
            this.recognition.stop();
          } else {
            this.wordConcat()
            this.recognition.start();
          }
        });
      }
      stop() {
        this.isStoppedSpeechRecog = true;
        this.wordConcat();
        this.recognition.stop();
      }
      reinit()
      {
        this.transcript_arr.length=0;
        this.confidence_arr.length=0;
        this.tempWords='';
        this.text='';
      }
      wordConcat() {
        this.text = this.text + ' ' + this.tempWords + '.';
        this.tempWords = '';
      }
    }
```

I use this `this.transcript_arr` in my typescript file when i have to clear this array i call `this.service.reinit();` this function but calling this function does not clear the array it holds previous values also. Any solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried with `this.transcript_arr = [];`?

Comment: @Misha Mashina yes I have tried but same issue

Comment: make sure there isn't any object that still hold reference to the old array. where you access `this.transcript` only in the class it self?

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally, you could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately someone can get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.

Comment: @dt170 I call stop and reinit function then only I try again to access this variable but it is retaining old values.

Comment: What about `confidence_arr` - is it cleared through the same method? If it is, can you find any relevant differences in the way you handle those two arrays throughout the project? It might be an overkill, but you can eventually try making the `transcript_arr` private, and handle it with getter and setter inside the service, to be sure it has full control over it.

Comment: @user3653474 can you please provide us a code snippet how you use it? `this.transcript_arr = []; ` `this.confidence_arr = []; ` should work. another thing is make sure you release the `addEventListener`

Comment: @dt170 i have checked `let temp_trans = e.results[last][0].transcript; ` in the `addEventlistener` returns previous results also is there any solution to clear there any solution to clear the previous results.